# How to disable raw string conversion suggestions from IntelliCode in Visual Studio?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2022, intellicode

I write C# files in VS2022.

Oftentimes I will write multi-line strings like so, and Intellisense will repeatedly (it takes < 40 characters) suggest to put it all on the same line, like so:

[image]

[image]

This is obviously awful, I don't want that, and I'm certainly not in the habit of writing multi-paragraph strings in one line, but it just keeps suggesting it. This would be fine... if a **space** didn't accept its suggestion, making it virtually impossible to write multi-line strings without turning C# suggestions off entirely.

Is there a way to turn off specifically IntelliCode suggestions to put multi-line strings on the same line? I see no such thing in the place I'd expect to find such an option should it exist:

[image]

Comment: Why do you not just write your multiline strings using "raw string literals"???

Comment: Is there a way to do that without breaking indentation ?

Comment: like this? https://dotnetfiddle.net/7NHbcn

Comment: Yes there is, see the link in my answer to "raw string literals"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you can see, the "[i]ntellicode suggestion is based on recent edits". This means, that it is based on edits you have made, and therefore does not map to any style rule. It proposes this, because you appear to have made similiar edits in the past. However there should be a **light bulb**, when hovering over this section, on which you can select **ignore** with a right click.
See https://devblogs.microsoft.com/visualstudio/making-repeated-edits-easier-with-intellicode-suggestions/.

However I would recommend to use "[raw string literals](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/tokens/raw-string)" either way. This is of course up to you though..

Comment: Thanks. Despite many years of programming I was still convinced raw string literals involved writing lines past the first with no indentation somehow...

Comment: Turns out this project is in C#10, so raw string literals aren't available yet...